# Consume java spring rest api and insert records to mysql table

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to consume a spring rest API and store the results into a staging table.
Here is what I tried. I am very new to java and spring, please forgive my mistakes.
My staging table name "greetingsstaging".
I am new to spring development, please help in understanding the issue.
I am using JPA and spring.

This is the main application.

```
package com.javatechie.spring.api;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.core.ParameterizedTypeReference;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import com.javatechie.spring.api.entty.Greetings;
import com.javatechie.spring.api.service.Greet;
import com.javatechie.spring.api.service.GreetInterface;
import com.javatechie.spring.api.service.GreetingsService;

@SpringBootApplication
public class GreetingsConsumerApplication {
    private static RestTemplate rs = new RestTemplate();
    private static String baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/api/Greetings";

    private static GreetInterface greetInterface;

    @Autowired
    public GreetingsConsumerApplication(GreetInterface theGreetInterface) {
        greetInterface = theGreetInterface;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GreetingsConsumerApplication.class, args);

        ResponseEntity<List<GreetingsService>> response = rs.exchange(baseUrl, HttpMethod.GET, null,
                new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<GreetingsService>>() {
                });
        List<GreetingsService> gs = response.getBody();

        for (GreetingsService g : gs) {

            Greetings greetings = new Greetings(g.getId(), g.getName(), g.getAge(), g.getAddress());
            System.out.println("Id : " + greetings.getId() + " name : " + greetings.getName() + " Age : "
                    + greetings.getAge() + " Address : " + greetings.getAddress());
            greetInterface.save(greetings);
        }

    }

}
```

Here is my service.

```
package com.javatechie.spring.api.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.javatechie.spring.api.entty.Greetings;
import com.javatechie.spring.api.repository.GreetingsRepository;

@Service
public class Greet implements GreetInterface{

    private GreetingsRepository repo;

    @Autowired
    public Greet(GreetingsRepository repo) {
        super();
        this.repo = repo;
    }
    @Override
    public void save(Greetings obj) {
        repo.save(obj);

    }
}
```

Here is the repository interface.

```
package com.javatechie.spring.api.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.javatechie.spring.api.entty.Greetings;

@Repository
public interface GreetingsRepository extends JpaRepository<Greetings, Integer> {

}
```

Here is my pojo class.

```
package com.javatechie.spring.api.entty;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="greetingsstaging")
public class Greetings {

    int id;
    String name;
    int age;
    String address;

    public Greetings(int id, String name, int age, String address) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Greetings [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", age=" + age + ", address=" + address + "]";
    }

}
```

I am getting following exception.

> Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'greetingsRepository' defined in com.javatechie.spring.api.repository.GreetingsRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.javatechie.spring.api.entty.Greetings

My main idea is to store the results from API into a staging table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing @Id annotation of Greetings class. Each JPA entity must have a primary key which uniquely identifies it.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="greetingsstaging")
public class Greetings {

    @Id
    int id;
}
```

Comment: Wow Govind , it worked like a wonder. thank you very much for pointing it out. Thank you very much. I had to add a default constructor in pojo class as well.